# Execute .exe file from c++ code + enter values

Tags: c++, input, call, exe

I'm relatively new to c++, and I'm just making some simple programs.

One of my programs will need to open up a different .exe file. This .exe file will ask for 2 or 3 file names, then run and exit.

Just to test this out, I created a simple_calc.exe file, that ask for value1, then value2 then multiply them.

So let's say I want to create a "call_other_file.exe" and automatically run "simple_calc.exe" with value1 and value2 taken from "call_other_file.exe"s file.
How can I proceed to do that?

After searching a bit, i see something like:
system("simple_calc.exe -val1 -val2").

But that doesn't work for me. Or I'm not sure how to define val1 and val2...

edit: the program I want to access (simple_calc.exe in the example), I can not change the code there, I don't have access to it's .cpp file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you really need to call another program and provide input for it you will need to redirect standard input for this program. How to do it depends on the platform and considering that you are relatively new it may be too hard. If you can modify the program you call so it uses command line arguments instead of standard input then `-val1 -val2` solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to have two separate programs communicate with one another, but the [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) function is probably the simplest; it just runs a string of text as though it were entered in a console window.

#### Basic example

The `main` program simply runs the `other` program with two arguments: `hello` and `world`.

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { return system("./other hello world"); }
```

The two arguments will be passed to the `other` program as C-style strings via the `argv[]` array. Note that they will be stored as the *second* and *third* elements, since the *first* item (`argv[0]`) will be the path to the program itself.

```
/* other.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { printf("%s\n", argv[i]); }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above programs will look like this:

```
hello
world

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.004 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

#### Arguments with spaces

As you may have noticed, arguments are space-separated. If you need to pass a string with spaces as a *single* parameter, you'll need to enclose it in quotes:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { return system("./other \"this is all one string\" \"and so is this\" bye"); }
```

This would produce the following result:

```
this is all one string
and so is this
bye

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.004 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

#### Non-string arguments

Since the arguments are given as strings, you'll need to convert them into numbers (using conversion functions such as [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strtod.html), [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html), or [`atof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/atof.html)) if necessary. Here's an updated version of `main.c`:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { return system("./other 4 6"); }
```

...and here's the corresponding `other.c` file:

```
/* other.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int total, i;
  for (total = 0, i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { total += atoi(argv[i]); }
  printf("TOTAL: %d\n", total);
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
TOTAL: 10

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.005 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

> i see something like: system("simple_calc.exe -val1 -val2")

It should work. The reason why that didn't work might be that you didn't put `int argc, char* argv[]` in your "simple_calc"'s main function.

```
//simple_calc.cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        cout << "Error: At least two argument must be exist.";
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    // After that, you can use 'argv' arguments to calculate what you want to calculate. Also, in order to calculate them, you also need to convert 'argv' to integer or double, since they are string or char array.
}
```

For more information on C++ comand-line arguments see this site below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

When you add the command-line arguments to your `simple_calc.cpp`, you can use this `simple_calc.exe val1 val2`. To call another program from your C++ program, you need system calls. In your main function;

`system('simple_calc.exe')`
You also need to know about how windows console work, if you are using windows. If you are using linux, its console commands are also different.

My suggestion is that you must first learn how consoles work different operating systems.

Comment: Thank you,
I don't have access to the .cpp file of the .exe file I will use. And the reason I'm not "learning" more is I don't have time and most of my coding is just mathematical using EIGEN. Thats is no problem for me, is just that one part of my program need to run another program that will create a .txt file I will read from.

Comment: Ok. If that's the case, still check the system calls, because you can call other programs only this way.